# How to save all warning in mariadb using Heidisql?

Tags: sql, mariadb, heidisql

I want to save all warnings in mariadb using Heidisql. But I have few problems.

1. If I run more than one SQL together, the latest SQL warnings will cover pervious SQL warnings. So I only can see the latest executed SQL warnings. Is it possible the latest executed SQL won't cover pervious SQL warnings?
2. `show warnings;` can only see 65535 records, how can I see more warnings?
3. How can I save those warnings to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to increase the `max_error_count` system variable, but this has a range of 0 to 65535. See the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_error_count).

I would recommend to fix some of the later problems in your SQL code, to decrease the number of warnings below 65535.